# How to iterate through string elements in a list side-by-side?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list:

```
cl = ["Food", "Clothing", "Automation"]
```

I want to print each character in each string of this list side-by-side:

```
 F  C  A  
 o  l  u  
 o  o  t  
 d  t  o  
    h     
    i     
    n     
    g
```

I have  managed to do this so far:

```
cl = ["Food", "Clothing", "Automation"]

for i in cl:
    for j in i:
        print(j)
```

Output:

```
F
o
o
d
C
l
o
t
h
i
n
g
A
u
t
o
m
a
t
i
o
n
```

How can I achieve my desired outcome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

cl = ['Food', 'Clothing', 'Automation']

for letters in zip_longest(*cl, fillvalue = ' '):
  print(*letters, sep = '  ')
```

Output:

```
F  C  A
o  l  u
o  o  t
d  t  o
   h  m
   i  a
   n  t
   g  i
      o
      n
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I add a space in between the two columns? In your answer there is only a single white-space between the columns, but i require two white spaces.

Comment: @AbuSafwanMdfarhan You can use the `sep` keyword of `print`, check the edit.